# Function that prints all unique combinations of numbers

Tags: go

I've been trying to create a function that prints all unique combinations of numbers with 1 digit (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 2 digits (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34 ... 89) and 3 digits (012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025 ... 789), starting from 0.

So far I've wrote this and have been testing different positions for the "if"s and "for"s without succeeding:

```
func ncombinations(x int) {
    if x == 3 {
        fmt.Print(a, b, c)
    }

    if x == 2 {
        fmt.Print(a, b)
    }

    if x == 3 {
        fmt.Print(a)
    }

    for a := 0; a < 10; a++ {
        for b := a + 1; b < 10; b++ {
            for c := b + 1; c < 10; c++ {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to make it work and optimize it?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233717/recursive-function-to-create-number-combinations-in-golang/35234599#35234599) provide a starting point? (the code in the question that is)

Comment: Hello Brits, thanks for your message. I think it does provide a starting point since it doesn't repeat the combination. Unfortunately I don't understand how to make it work still.

Comment: The code in the question I linked gives you a starting point (you may need to tweak it a little). If you are still having trouble then show what you have tried and the issue you now have (this looks like a homework problem and, while I'm happy to help, I'm not going to do it for you - [see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/11810946)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive but working and easy to understand solutions for your problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    nCombinations(3)
}

func nCombinations(input int) {
    if input == 1 {
        for i := 0; i <= 9; i++ {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    } else if input == 2 {
        for i := 0; i <= 99; i++ {
            if i <= 9 {
                fmt.Println("0" + strconv.Itoa(i))
            } else {
                fmt.Println(i)
            }
        }
    } else if input == 3 {
        for i := 0; i <= 999; i++ {
            if i <= 9 {
                fmt.Println("00" + strconv.Itoa(i))
            } else if i <= 99 {
                fmt.Println("0" + strconv.Itoa(i))
            } else {
                fmt.Println(i)
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("out of range")
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified [to this](https://go.dev/play/p/lgkUV74MZjL) but I suspect it fails on the "unique combinations" bit (it will print `001`, `010`, and `100`). This may be intentional as you did mention its naive...

Comment: Hello Dharman, hisam and Brits. Thanks for your answers and editing. Unfortunately these two options are not repeating the unique combinations – as Brits have pointed out in his comment.